# GET query missing with apollo-server-lambda in CloudFront Behaviors

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I used the **apollo-server-lambda** package to create my lambda function with the serverless framework, as we can see, everything went well.

```
https://28d1lielb9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod
```

Now I working to place graphql in the same subdomain as my application in CloudFront and I am getting the error `GET query missing`.

```
https://forms.ciro-maciel.me/g/p/
```

I did several tests with the path, but I was not successful.

When did we receive the message GET query missing?

How can I correctly configure my environment?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

try to understand the codes and note that a playground presentation is conditioned by the code:

```
const acceptHeader = event.headers ['Accept'] || event.headers ['accept'];
```

with a log of the CloudFront call make sure the **Accept** header was not passed to a source.

then in **Behaviors**, obtain a configuration to be able to pass this header, as you can see below.

[CloudFront - Behaviors - Accept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXzbf.png)

Configured and working!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ciro Cesar Maciel.
I had to add the header as following:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
```

Edit the origin and add the header:

[image]